# Algebraically determine the x-intercept of $y=2^{x+2}-3$

Tags: calculus

Algebraically determine the $x$-intercept of $y=2^{x+2}-3$

Any help would be much appreciated... looking at the question it is clear to me that there are no real intercepts for $x$ but there is for $y$. If I look on the graph I can point out that there is a X:INT of $x$=-0.415-

Comment: I solved for the Y INT: I got {yER:y>-3}

Comment: So you are looking for $x_0$ such that $2^{x_0+2}=3$. What is the inverse function of exponential $2^x$?

Answer (score 5):

You want

$$2^{x+2}-3=0$$

so $$2^{x+2}=3$$ which means $$x+2=\log_2 3$$ and finally $$x=\log_23-2$$

Answer (score 2):

To find the intersection of $f(x):=2^{x+2}-3$ and $y=0$ you must solve the equation
$$
2^{x+2}-3 = 0
$$
which gives 
$$
x= \log_23-2
$$
Comes handy to know:
$$
\log_a x = \frac{\log_b x}{\log_b a}
$$
You then have
$$
\log_23 = \frac{\ln 3}{\ln 2}
$$